# How to pull all data from API JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, foreach, axios

I have below code. I only pulls 1 row since I typed `[1]` in array. But, there are like 20 rows in that JSON API.

How can I use `forEach` loop in this code to get all rows? I greatly appreciate any help.

```
function getTodos() {
    axios
        .get('https://api.fiscaldata.treasury.gov/services/api/fiscal_service/v1/accounting/od/rates_of_exchange?fields=country_currency_desc,exchange_rate,record_date&filter=country_currency_desc:in:(Canada-Dollar),record_date:gte:2020-01-20', {
            country_currency_desc: 'Currency',
            exchange_rate: 'last price',
            record_date: 'date',
        })
        .then((res) => showOutput(res))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}

function showOutput(res) {
    document.getElementById('row').innerHTML = `
        <th>
            ${JSON.stringify(res.data.data[1].record_date)}
        </th> 
        <th>
            ${JSON.stringify(res.data.data[1].country_currency_desc)}
        </th> 
        <th>
            ${JSON.stringify(res.data.data[1].exchange_rate)}
        </th> 
    `
}
```

[Here is the image of how app looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6bos.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the row elements for each todo, then create child elements for each child of the todo. To give you an idea:

```js
function appendElement(parentId, tag = 'div', newId, content) {
  // create a new div element
  const newEl = document.createElement(tag);
  if (newId) newEl.id = newId

  // and give it some content
  if (content) {
    const newContent = document.createTextNode(content);
    // add the text node to the newly created div
    newEl.appendChild(newContent);
  }

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
  if (parentId) {
    const par = document.getElementById(parentId);
    par.appendChild(newEl);
  }

  return newEl;
}

const todos = [{
    id: 0,
    label: "todo0",
    children: [
      "2022-06-30",
      "Canada dollar",
      "1.292"
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    label: "todo1",
    children: [
      "2022-07-02",
      "US dollar",
      "1.25"
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: "todo2",
    children: [
      "2022-07-04",
      "KZT",
      "1.3"
    ]
  },
]

function init() {
  todos.forEach((todo, todoIdx) => {
    appendElement('table', 'tr', 'row-' + todoIdx);
    appendElement('row-' + todoIdx, 'td', undefined, todo.label)
    todo.children.forEach((child, childIdx) => {
      appendElement('row-' + todoIdx, 'td', undefined, child)
    })
  })
}

window.onload=init
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Label</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Currency</th>
    <th>Exchange rate</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If instead of arrays of strings for children you have arrays of objects, instead of the nested `forEach` loop you can just manually `appendElement()` every cell of the row